# Create comma delimited datapair string from numeric arrays in MATLAB

Tags: string, list, matlab, csv

I have two arrays of values:

```
t = [0; 1; 2];
q = [0; 100; 200];
```

I need those to be one string that's like:

```
str = '0, 0, 1, 100, 2, 200';
```

I can't see a nice way to do it in MATLAB (R2017a) without using a loop. I'd like to avoid that if possible as there's a pretty large array of values and a lot of files and it'll take forever.

Any ideas?

Comment: "it'll take forever" You shouldn't say this until you've tried it. Loops are no longer slow in MATLAB, and haven't been for 15 years.

Comment: Not really a particularly constructive comment when I'm looking for advice.  I've not been using MATLAB for as long as 15 years but I've definitely come across slow loops in the past, especially when parsing multiple long files and doing a lot of I/O within them.

Comment: I think it is very useful advice. I see tons of questions here about “I can do it with a loop but would like to do without”, and “I think a loop will be too slow”. Then they get advice for a vectorized solution, and I come along and show how the loop version is actually faster. So: people waste time optimizing something that doesn’t need optimizing, don’t time their optimized solution, and end up with slower code than if they’d just wrote a freaking loop. All because of the myth that “MATLAB loops are slow”, which was the case 15 years ago but hasn’t been true since.

Comment: There is a saying in computer science: premature optimization is the root of all evil. — if you have a solution that proves too slow for your needs, post it here and ask for how to make it faster. Don’t ask for a vectorized solution before trying out the loop version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible approach. This works for integer numbers, or if you want a fixed number of decimals in the string representation:

```
t = [0; 1; 2];
q = [0; 100; 200];
tq = reshape([t(:).'; q(:).'], 1, []);
s = sprintf('%i, ',tq); % or change '%i' to something like '%.5f'
s = s(1:end-2)
```

Result:

```
s =

    '0, 0, 1, 100, 2, 200'
```

---

If you have non-integer numbers and want the number of decimals in the representation to be chosen automatically, you can use `mat2str` instead of `sprintf`,  but then you need to deal with the spaces using `regexpre` or a similar function:

```
t = [0; 1; 2];
q = [0; 100; 200];
tq = reshape([t(:).'; q(:).'], 1, [])
s = regexprep(num2str(tq), '\s+', ', ');
```

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was looking for. I'd tried the reshape initially but I'd been missing the way of getting them into the right order, rather then just a list of t values and then a list of q's.

Answer (score 2):

Combine `compose` with `strjoin`:

```
t = [0; 1; 2];
q = [0; 100; 200];
str = strjoin(compose('%d', [t(:)'; q(:)']), ', ');
```

Output:

```
str = 
    '0, 0, 1, 100, 2, 200'
```

For non integer numbers, use: `%f` instead of `%d`

Comment: Unfortunately this is outputting the values in the wrong order; I was looking for a datapair list where I'd have [t1, q1, t2, q2, t3, q3] as shown in the question.

Comment: @LADransfield: I updated my answer, now the result is in the order: [t1, q1, t2, q2, t3, q3] as in the question.